# Snowball analyzer vs language analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

Just trying to understand what is the better approach for morphological search with [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both do the same thing - normalize words to some level.

There's just one difference - snowball analyzer is pretty much tokenizer + snowball filter, while english language analyzer is using `porter_stem` and `possessive_english` stemmers + other filters.

I, myself, wouldn't use both of these OOB since they're too aggressive and normalize words way too much and words with different meaning are indexed identically.

In order to fix that, I'd recommend to switch to `kstem`, dictionary stemmers or a combination of both of them to get desired result.

Comment: Do you mean to use a standard analyzer with custom token filters (kstem)?